# How can I output pagination via Bootstrap to php?

Tags: php

I wrote a code that displays two records per page

```
$page = isset($_GET['page']) ? $_GET['page'] : 1;
$limit = 2;
$offset = $limit * ($page - 1);
$res = mysqli_query($link,"SELECT * FROM profile LIMIT $limit OFFSET $offset");
```

If in the browser I start to manually write the address of the form `http://mysite/posts.php?page=2`

How can I do all this with Bootstrap pagination?

```
<nav aria-label="Page navigation example">
    <ul class="pagination">
        <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">1</a></li>
        <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">2</a></li>
        <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">3</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: First, you need know the exact count of the list (all profiles), then use simple math to know the number of pages for `$limit` results per page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```sql
CREATE TABLE `page` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(25) NOT NULL
);
INSERT INTO `page` (`id`, `name`) VALUES
(1, 'home'),
(2, 'contact'),
(3, 'about'),
(4, 'game'),
(5, 'insert'),
(6, 'delete'),
(7, 'add'),
(8, 'update'),
(9, 'cart'),
(10, 'check'),
(11, 'tasks'),
(12, 'message'),
(13, 'friends'),
(14, 'notification'),
(15, 'music'),
(16, 'play');
```

```php
<?php
    $con = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','pagination');
    $per_page = 5;
    $crr_p = $page = $_GET['page'] ?? 0;
    if(isset($_GET['page']))
    {
        $crr_p = $_GET['page'];
        $page = $_GET['page']*$per_page;
    }
    $rowcount = mysqli_num_rows(mysqli_query($con,"select * from page"));
    $pages = ceil($rowcount/$per_page);

    $sql = "select * from page limit $page, $per_page";
    $res = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
?>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/bootstrap.min.css" />
        <script src="assets/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <title>Pagination</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
        <h2>System Pgination</h2>
        
        <ul class="list-group col-md-3">
            <?php while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)){ ?>
                    <li class="list-group-item"><?=$row['name']?></li>
            <?php } ?>
        </ul>
        <br>
        <ul class="pagination">
            <?php for($i = 0; $i < $pages; $i++): $active = $crr_p==$i?'active':'' ?>
                    <li class="page-item <?=$active?>">
                        <a class="page-link"
                           href="<?=$active?'javascript:void(0)':'?page='.$i ?>">
                            <?=$i+1?>
                        </a>
                    </li>
            <?php endfor; ?>
        </ul>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```